# Ruby on rails TypeError (can't cast Hash to integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class in the controller as a client API, it was working without checking organization_id, organization_id is linked to observation through user and memberships.

```
 def update
    @observation = Observation.find(params[:id])
    if params[:state] == 'submitted' && @observation.submit
      if @observation.source.source_type == 'registered'
        @user = User.find(id: @observation.source.source_identifier)
        @memberships = Membership.find(user_id: @user.id)
        if @memberships.present? &&@memberships.where("organization_id IS NOT NULL")
          @observation.approve
        end
      end

      render json: { createdAt: @observation.created_at }, status: 200
    else
      render nothing: true, status: 406
    end
  end
```

TypeError (can't cast Hash to integer):
  app/controllers/api/client/v1/observations_controller.rb:106:in `update'
which is line:

```
@user = User.find(id: @observation.source.source_identifier)
```

Table structure:

```
  # create_table "sources", force: true do |t|
  #   t.string   "device_id"
  #   t.string   "source_type"
  #   t.string   "source_identifier"
  #   ...

  # create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  #     #   t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  #   t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
  #    ...
  #   t.string   "first_name"
  #   t.string   "last_name"
  #   t.string   "phone"
  #   t.integer  "source_id"
  #   ...

  # create_table "memberships", force: true do |t|
  #   t.integer  "user_id"
  #   t.integer  "organization_id"
  #   t.datetime "verified_at"
  #   ...
```

Comment: Unless you overrode Rails, you are trying to search for a unique table ID using a string, so that is the source of your error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ActiveRecord::Base#find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) takes one argument: an `Integer`.  This should be the ID of the record you're attempting to find.

Instead of `User.find(id: ...)`, do this:

```
@user = User.find(@observation.source.source_identifier)
```

However please note that [`#find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) *will* raise if it cannot find the source; if you don't want that, you probably would want to use `#find_by_id` or [`where(id: ...).first`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-first) instead.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are running Rails 4+, to find a record by attribute, simply use this pattern:

```
Model.find_by(attribute_name: attribute_value)
```

So, in your case:

```
@user = User.find_by(source_identifier: @observation.source.source_identifier)
```

Comment: That's odd, I can't seem to find that anywhere in the documentation, and when I tried to run that locally, [I ran into an error](https://gist.github.com/medcat/3a86871c97b848ea181d).  Do you mind providing a source on that?

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy fixed my typo.  Documentation is [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by).

Comment: I was worried I was out of the loop for a moment there D: